# Lists of applications or services which allow sign on as either SAML or OpenID Connect Service Providers/Relying Parties?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, saml, openid-connect

I am trying to make the case for my sector (public libraries) facilitating access to some online services for patrons by supporting either SAML or OpenID Connect as *identity providers*. The case would be much strengthened by being able to point to a list of existing 3rd party services that can integrate as Service Providers/Relying Partners using either SAML or OpenID Connect (I do realize they are different).

So far most of my searches have turned up lists of software libraries that can provide SP/RP capabilities but no list of actual online services or applications which can support these other than this one https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.1.x/integration/Configuring-SAML-SP-Integrations.html for SAML integrations.

Does anyone know of other such lists that can help make the case?

Answer (score 1):

I think there would be too many to list.

Although adoption may not yet be as broad as SAML within the enterprise within the "Cloud" and API space I would say adoption is higher than any other methods.

Is there some specific industry you are looking at?

A good indicator of adoption is the number of questions here for OpenID Connect (and OAuth as many people do not understand the differences).

OpenID Foundation tracks [Certified OpenID Connect Implementations](https://openid.net/developers/certified/) but most companies, at least hose not selling or hosting OpenID Connect services, do not bother and many use one of the Certified OpenID Connect Implementations.

Comment: I agree an exhaustive list would be impossible. But even an non-exhaustive one would be super helpful. In terms of an "industry" - so I am primarily looking at applications aimed at individual end users that public libraries might consider offering as a service to patrons. For example - we have a sandstorm instance that I'd love to allow patrons to access with their library identities via SAML. The more such examples I can cite, the easier it is for libraries to see the potential in moving towards open standards based auth.

Comment: maybe a little but not really - it doesn't indicate if these are acting as identity providers or consumers, and it is apps/services that can consume SAML/OAuth/OpenID Conenct that I am primarily looking for. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See the list of SPs on the [InCommon Participants List](https://www.incommon.org/federation/incommon-federation-entities/). Those are all Service Providers that federate with InCommon, one of the largest academic federations in the world. Those ALL speak SAML. You'll find a lot of services there, including more than a few that I work for. InCommon is specific to higher ed, but looking through the list you'll see companies that have joined this federation to make it easier to work with those university members, and they all speak SAML.

You might look at [OpenAthens](https://openathens.org/) as I think they cater somewhat to libraries.

Look at things like the Okta and PingFederate application integrations which exist to get an idea of what sort of apps support SAML. You aren't going to find a comprehensive list. A better solution would be to look at the apps that your sector uses, and scout out whether they use SAML. For example, you mentioned [Sandstorm](https://docs.sandstorm.io/en/latest/administering/for-work/) in a comment above... and they support SAML.

Also, re: OAuth/OIDC vs. SAML. This argument will go on for days. It's not that difficult to choose a product which supports both.

Comment: much agreed with that last paragraph

Comment: InCommons lists of SPs is super helpful, thanks you!!

Comment: totally agree regarding interminability of OAuth/OIDC vs SAML debate - we're looking at Apero's CAS (as we want to stay open source.) Are there others you admire that can serve multiple protocols/methods and are also open source?

Comment: @nessman I like CAS, however, you might also take a look at [Gluu](https://www.gluu.org/)

Comment: @KellenMurphy I had seen Gluu - am always slightly concerned by "community source" versions financially supported by closed source enterprise enhancements (can sometimes be a bait and switc), but your comment is causing me to take another look, thanks!

Comment: @nessman It's worth taking a look. I was skeptical at first, because they did just layer a bunch of open source packages together, it seems. However, the stuff the layered together is stuff that's NOT exactly friendly to spin up.